# How to get filenames and paths of files in wp-content/uploads folder?

Tags: python, php, wordpress

I have no knowledge of php or Js and i need to have a text file with paths/filenames of all images that are in the wp-content/uploads folder of my Wordpress site so i can create an excel spreadsheet to upoload products with image references of path from this text file. I have some excel/vba knowledge to do it.

I have found this function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/list_files/ in developes wordpress. Where can i place this code to make tests?

I tried also to make it happen with Python that i have also very minimum knowledge with no luck. I expeted to logIn to my wp-admin with python through login.php page and then access wp-content/uploads folder but did not make it.

```
import os, import requests
def list_files(directory):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print(filepath)

# Set your WordPress login URL and credentials
wp_login = 'mySite/login.php'
wp_admin = 'mySite/wp-admin/'
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'

# Create a session and set the necessary headers
with requests.Session() as s:
    headers = {'Cookie': 'wordpress_test_cookie=WP Cookie check'}
    data = {
        'log': "myUserName",
        'pwd': "myPass",
        'wp-submit': 'Log In',
        'redirect_to': wp_admin,
        'testcookie': '1'
    }
# Log in to WordPress
    s.post(wp_login, headers=headers, data=data)

# Example usage
uploads_directory = 'mySite/wp-content/uploads/'
list_files(uploads_directory)
```

Comment: Open your site in browser and open Developer tools. Now login and go to *media*. Check network request which have `..../media?` in it's url, check it's content if it's what you need you can request same with necessary cookie, parameters by analyzing this request

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote a small plugin for this task. Need something similar in the near future. Using the WordPress internal function `list_files` was the right way to go. However, `list_files` is an admin function (only available in the backend) and is only loaded when the `admin_init` hook is triggered. Therefore you have to put everything into an `action_hook`.

About the plugin itself. In general, any folder can be crawled and the files to be considered can be selected. The result does not always have to refer to images only. But this can be defined in the plugin settings.

What else? The dates of last modification (folder to be crawled, saved file (if any) and the plugin file) are compared so that the text file is not rewritten with every backend call. If the saved file is older than the folder, the file is rewritten. The same applies if the file is older than the plugin file.

All plugin settings are briefly explained and I think they are self-explanatory. However, I have to go into more detail on three of them.

`levels` - folder crawl depth
If you organize your uploads in monthly and yearly folders, the min. required setting is `3`. If you disabled this WordPress-Setting, `levels` can be set to `1`.
This prevents files (in your case images) from subfolders from being included in the result. But what, as mentioned before, if month/year-based folders are used?
We have another setting for this case ....

`exclusions` - exclude subfolders from being crawled
If you cannot set `levels` to `1`, you can still use the `exclusions` setting to prevent subfolders from being included in the result. Suppose a plugin has created
a subfolder called **"example"** in your upload folder and another plugin has created a folder called **"test"**. Then you can exclude them as follows:
`'exclusions' => ['example', 'test'],`

`private` - output file is private
If set to `true`, the file permissions are set to `0600`. This means that the file can no longer be accessed directly in the browser (read and write permission is granted to the owner, and no permission is granted to the group and user). Default value is `0664`.

#### WordPress integration

**AS A PLUGIN**

1. Copy the entire code from the code block into an empty text file.
2. Adjust the settings to your needs.
3. Save the file as `file-list-creator.php`.
4. Log in to WordPress and go to the plugin page.
5. Click `Add new plugin` and upload the file.
6. Activate the plugin.
7. Done.

Standard plugins do show on the Plugins page and can be quickly activated or deactivated from there.

**AS A MU-PLUGIN**

1. Copy the entire code from the code block into an empty text file.
2. Adjust the settings to your needs.
3. Save the file as `file-list-creator.php`.
4. Connect to your FTP server and open the `wp-content` folder.
5. Ceate a new folder `mu-plugins` if it doesn't already exist.
6. Upload `file-list-creator.php` to this folder.
7. Done.

Must-use plugins (mu-plugins) do not show on the Plugins page, although they do appear in a special Must-Use section. Mu-plugins cannot be disabled except by removing the plugin file from the must-use directory. Read more about [Must-use plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/plugins/mu-plugins/).

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WP File List Creator
 * Desciption: Generates a file that lists the contents of a directory.
 * Author URI: https://stackoverflow.com/users/20896315/ferris
 * Version: 1.0
 */

namespace WPFLC;

/**
 * Disallow direct access.
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' );
    exit;
}

/**
 * The plugin settings.
 */
new WP_File_List_Creator([

    /* Required */

    # folder to be crawled (path)
    'folder' => wp_get_upload_dir()[ 'basedir' ],

    # output file name without extension (string)
    'file_name' => 'image-list',


    /* Optional */

    # user role fore execution [ 'admin', 'editor', 'author', 'none' ]
    # default = 'admin'
    'caps' => 'admin',

    # folder crawl depth [1-100]
    # default = 100
    'levels' => 3,

    # include-only file formats (array)
    # default = []
    'extensions' => [ 'avif', 'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'svg', 'webp' ],

    # exclude subfolders from being crawled (array)
    # default = []
    'exclusions' => [],

    # output file type ['csv'|'txt']
    # default = 'csv'
    'file_type' => 'txt',

    # output location ['root'|'uploads']
    # default = 'uploads'
    'location' => 'uploads',

    # output list type ['paths'|'urls'|'both']
    # default = 'both'
    'list_type' => 'paths',

    # output item separator (string)
    # default = '; '
    'separator' => '; ',

    # output file is private (bool)
    # default = false
    'private' => false,

    # csv file column names (string[])
    # default = 'PATH' / 'URL'
    'labels' => [
        'paths' => 'PATH',
        'urls'  => 'URL'
    ]
]);

/**
 * The plugin class.
 */
class WP_File_List_Creator {

    /**
     * The plugin options.
     *
     * @access private
     */
    private $options = array();

    /**
     * The class constructor.
     */
    public function __construct( array $options ) {

        $this->options = $this->set_options( $options );

        if ( ! empty( $this->options ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ), 10, 0 );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback for the admin_init hook.
     */
    public function admin_init() : void {

        clearstatcache();

        $update_file = true;

        if ( ! is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( empty( $this->options ) || ! is_array( $this->options ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $this->options[ 'caps' ] ) && ! current_user_can( $this->options[ 'caps' ] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! file_exists( $this->options[ 'folder' ] ) || ! is_dir( $this->options[ 'folder' ] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $this->options[ 'location' ] === 'root' ) {
            $destination = ABSPATH . $this->options[ 'file_name' ] . '.' . $this->options[ 'file_type' ];
        } else {
            $destination = trailingslashit( wp_get_upload_dir()[ 'basedir' ] ) . $this->options[ 'file_name' ] . '.' . $this->options[ 'file_type' ];
        }

        if ( file_exists( $destination ) && is_file( $destination ) ) {

            $last_modified_folder = filemtime( $this->options[ 'folder' ] );
            $last_modified_output = filemtime( $destination );
            $last_modified_source = filemtime( __FILE__ );

            if ( $last_modified_folder < $last_modified_output ) {

                $update_file = false;

                if ( ! $update_file ) {
                    if ( $last_modified_source >= $last_modified_output ) {
                        $update_file = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $update_file ) {

            $files = list_files( $this->options[ 'folder' ], $this->options[ 'levels' ], $this->options[ 'exclusions' ] );

            if ( ! empty( $files ) && is_array( $files ) ) {

                if ( $this->options[ 'file_type' ] === 'csv' ) {
                    $result = $this->create_csv_file( $files, $destination );
                } elseif ( $this->options[ 'file_type' ] === 'txt' ) {
                    $result = $this->create_text_file( $files, $destination );
                } else {
                    $result = false;
                }

                if ( $result && $this->options[ 'private' ] === true ) {
                    @chmod( $destination, 0600 );
                } else {
                    @chmod( $destination, 0644 );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for creating an csv file containing the file list.
     *
     * @param  array  $files       The collected files.
     * @param  string $destination The destination path.
     * @return bool
     */
    public function create_csv_file( array $files, string $destination ) : bool {

        $column_names = [];
        $output_data = [];
        $result = false;

        if ( empty( $files ) || empty( $destination ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'both' ) {
            $column_names = [
                $this->options[ 'labels' ][ 'paths' ],
                $this->options[ 'labels' ][ 'urls' ]
            ];
        } elseif ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'paths' ) {
            $column_names = [
                $this->options[ 'labels' ][ 'paths' ]
            ];
        } elseif ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'urls' ) {
            $column_names = [
                $this->options[ 'labels' ][ 'urls' ]
            ];
        }

        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            if ( is_file( $file ) && in_array( strtolower( pathinfo( $file )[ 'extension' ] ), $this->options[ 'extensions' ] ) ) {
                if ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'both' ) {
                    array_push( $output_data, [ $file, str_replace( ABSPATH, trailingslashit( site_url() ), $file ) ] );
                } elseif ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'urls' ) {
                    array_push( $output_data, [ str_replace( ABSPATH, trailingslashit( site_url() ), $file ) ] );
                } elseif ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'paths' ) {
                    array_push( $output_data, [ $file ] );
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $output_data ) ) {

            array_unshift( $output_data, $column_names );

            $f = @fopen( $destination, 'w' );

            if ( $f !== false ) {
                if ( @flock( $f, LOCK_EX ) ) {
                    foreach ( $output_data as $row ) {
                        @fputcsv( $f, $row, ';' );
                    }
                    @fflush( $f );
                    @flock( $f, LOCK_UN );
                    $result = true;
                }
                @fclose( $f );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for creating a text file containing the file list.
     *
     * @param  array  $files       The collected files.
     * @param  string $destination The destination path.
     * @return bool
     */
    public function create_text_file( array $files, string $destination ) : bool {

        $result = false;
        $output_data = '';

        if ( empty( $files ) || empty( $destination ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            if ( is_file( $file ) && in_array( strtolower( pathinfo( $file )[ 'extension' ] ), $this->options[ 'extensions' ] ) ) {
                if ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'both' ) {
                    $output_data .= $file . $this->options[ 'separator' ] . str_replace( ABSPATH, trailingslashit( site_url() ), $file ) . "\r\n";
                } elseif ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'urls' ) {
                    $output_data .= str_replace( ABSPATH, trailingslashit( site_url() ), $file ) . "\r\n";
                } elseif ( $this->options[ 'list_type' ] === 'paths' ) {
                    $output_data .= $file . "\r\n";
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( str_replace( array( "\r", "\n", " " ), '', $output_data ) !== '' ) {
            $result = ( bool ) @file_put_contents( $destination, $output_data, LOCK_EX );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for converting a user role to a respective capability.
     *
     * @access private
     * @param  string $role The user role.
     * @return string
     */
    private function role_2_cap( string $role ) : string {
        switch ( $role ) {
            case 'admin':
                return 'manage_options';
            case 'editor':
                return 'publish_pages';
            case 'author':
                return 'publish_posts';
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for setting up the plugin options.
     *
     * @access private
     * @param  array $options The custom options.
     * @return array
     */
    private function set_options( array $options ) : array {

        if ( empty( $options ) ||
            empty( $options[ 'folder' ] ) ||
            empty( $options[ 'file_name' ] ) ||
            ! is_string( $options[ 'folder' ] ) ||
            ! is_string( $options[ 'file_name' ] )
        ) {
            return [];
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options[ 'caps' ] ) && is_string( $options[ 'caps' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'caps' ] = $this->role_2_cap( $options[ 'caps' ] );
        } else {
            $options[ 'caps' ] = 'manage_options';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options[ 'list_type' ] ) && is_string( $options[ 'list_type' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'list_type' ] = strtolower( $options[ 'list_type' ] );
            $options[ 'list_type' ] = in_array( $options[ 'list_type' ], [ 'both', 'paths', 'urls' ] ) ? $options[ 'list_type' ] : 'both';
        } else {
            $options[ 'location' ] = 'both';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options[ 'location' ] ) && is_string( $options[ 'location' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'location' ] = strtolower( $options[ 'location' ] );
            $options[ 'location' ] = in_array( $options[ 'location' ], [ 'root', 'uploads' ] ) ? $options[ 'location' ] : 'uploads';
        } else {
            $options[ 'location' ] = 'uploads';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options[ 'file_type' ] ) && is_string( $options[ 'file_type' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'file_type' ] = strtolower( $options[ 'file_type' ] );
            $options[ 'file_type' ] = in_array( $options[ 'file_type' ], [ 'csv', 'txt' ] ) ? $options[ 'file_type' ] : 'csv';
        } else {
            $options[ 'file_type' ] = 'csv';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options[ 'levels' ] ) && is_int( $options[ 'levels' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'levels' ] = in_array( $options[ 'levels' ], range( 1, 100 ) ) ? $options[ 'levels' ] : 100;
        } else {
            $options[ 'levels' ] = 100;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options[ 'extensions' ] ) && is_array( $options[ 'extensions' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'extensions' ] = array_map( function ( $value ) {
                return ltrim( strtolower( $value ), '.' );
            }, $options[ 'extensions' ] );
        } else {
            $options[ 'extensions' ] = [];
        }

        if ( empty( $options[ 'exclusions' ] ) || ! is_array( $options[ 'exclusions' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'exclusions' ] = [];
        }

        if ( empty( $options[ 'labels' ][ 'paths' ] ) || ! is_string( $options[ 'labels' ][ 'paths' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'labels' ][ 'paths' ] = 'PATH';
        }

        if ( empty( $options[ 'labels' ][ 'urls' ] ) || ! is_string( $options[ 'labels' ][ 'urls' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'labels' ][ 'urls' ] = 'URL';
        }

        if ( empty( $options[ 'separator' ] ) || ! is_string( $options[ 'separator' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'separator' ] = '; ';
        }

        if ( empty( $options[ 'private' ] ) || ! is_bool( $options[ 'private' ] ) ) {
            $options[ 'private' ] = false;
        }

        $options[ 'file_name' ] = pathinfo( $options[ 'file_name' ], PATHINFO_FILENAME );
        $options[ 'folder' ] = realpath( $options[ 'folder' ] );

        return $options;
    }
}
```